# git rev-parse --show-toplevel to not resolve symbolic links

Tags: git, directory, symlink

When my project dir is a symbolic link to where the actual directory is stored, then `--show-toplevel` will output the actual path, probably called "physical path". So for example, if I'm in the **right** path visible here:

```
ln -s /home/me/.hidden_projects_storage/newproject /home/me/workspace/newproject.git
```

then `--show-toplevel` will output:

```
/home/me/.hidden_projects_storage/newproject
```

I'm runnign `git rev-parse` from top-level directory, `newproject.git`. Can I somehow have symbolic path returned?

Answer (score 2):

Try to run this:

```
echo $(cd $(git rev-parse --show-cdup) .; pwd)
```

Comment: Tried it and it returns unmodified, physical path

Comment: My mistake, by default `realpath` follows symlinks. There is an option which disables this feature (`-s`), but `realpath` still fails when you run it from repository's top-level directory (because in such case `git-rev-parse` returns empty string).

I've changed my answer, currently it doesn't use `realpath` anymore, so it should be more flexible and portable.